# Add a new row and create a slide in one for that row have not yet been created

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I am a teacher trying to simply making a daily agenda. I have a Google Sheet with the information that I need to add to daily slides and a Google Slide with the template that I want. So far with my code, I can do that, however, it updates everything every time.

I want to be able to add a new row and it only create slides for the ones that have not yet been created. I would also love if the newest slides were at the beginning of the presentation rather that at the end but I think I know how to do that. ANY HELP IS MUCH APPRECIATED!

My spreadsheet includes the information (Date, Topic, EQ, I can Statements and Objectives) and it is adding this information to Google Slides into a template that I created. Then with the code, I have it sending a url link back to the spreadsheet for me to view that specific slide.

| TYPE DATE | DATE | Topic | EQ | I can statement | Objectives | URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/29/2022 | Monday, August 29 | Day 1 Information | How can I be successful in my Math 2 class? | I can pass Math 2! | -Syllabus -Class Expectations -Procedures -All About You | https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/199316s_a4J3FrILLIG3UxYCAme8xR7h3s7F45rlLR14/present#slide=id.SLIDES_API1087144262_624 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

You can view a copy of the spreadsheet including more sample data here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dlS6rQqxz8t3YvHwMj8CxmVYPkCtJqrBpaZEAViQvx8/edit?usp=sharing

The problem is that when I run the script, it creates new slides for every single row in the spreadsheet and I would prefer for it to only add a slide for a new row. I thought there might be a way to use the date and url columns and just run for when they are not null however I do not know how to do that and can't seem to find the answer online. I am very very new to scripts and I am trying to learn.

This is what I have so far that is working just running everything.

```
// The onOpen function is executed automatically every time a Spreadsheet is loaded
function onOpen() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var menuEntries = [];
// When the user clicks on "addMenuExample" then "Menu Entry 1", the function function1 is
// executed.
menuEntries.push({name: "Run Function", functionName: "createOneSlidePerRow"});


ss.addMenu("Create Slides", menuEntries);
}

function createOneSlidePerRow() {

// Replace <INSERT_SLIDE_DECK_ID> wih the ID of your 
// Google Slides presentation.
let masterDeckID = "199316s_a4J3FrILLIG3UxYCAme8xR7h3s7F45rlLR14";

// Open the presentation and get the slides in it.
let deck = SlidesApp.openById(masterDeckID);
let slides = deck.getSlides();

// The 2nd slide is the template that will be duplicated
// once per row in the spreadsheet.
let masterSlide = slides[1];

// Load data from the spreadsheet.
let dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange();
let sheetContents = dataRange.getValues();

// Save the header in a variable called header
let header = sheetContents.shift();

// Create an array to save the data to be written back to the sheet.
// We'll use this array to save links to the slides that are created.
let updatedContents = [];

// Reverse the order of rows because new slides will
// be inserted at the top. Without this, the order of slides
// will be the inverse of the ordering of rows in the sheet. 
sheetContents.reverse();

// For every row, create a new slide by duplicating the master slide
// and replace the template variables with data from that row.
sheetContents.forEach(function (row) {

// Insert a new slide by duplicating the master slide.
let slide = masterSlide.duplicate();

// Populate data in the slide that was created
slide.replaceAllText("{{Date}}", row[1]);
slide.replaceAllText("{{Topic}}", row[2]);
slide.replaceAllText("{{EQ}}", row[3]);
 slide.replaceAllText("{{I can}}", row[4]);
  slide.replaceAllText("{{Objectives}}", row[5]);

  // Create the URL for the slide using the deck's ID and the ID
  // of the slide.
  let slideUrl = `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/${deck.getId()}/present#slide=id.${slide.getObjectId()}`;

// Add this URL to the 4th column of the row and add this row
// to the data to be written back to the sheet.
row[6] = slideUrl;
updatedContents.push(row);
});

// Add the header back (remember it was removed using 
// sheetContents.shift())
updatedContents.push(header);

// Reverse the array to preserve the original ordering of 
// rows in the sheet.
updatedContents.reverse();

// Write the updated data back to the Google Sheets spreadsheet.
dataRange.setValues(updatedContents);



}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please describe the relevant parts of your spreadsheet structure, add some sample data a brief description of how the spreadsheet and the script are used so other might better understand the problem. P.S. It's very likely that you will have to add a column to set if the slide was already created or not and in your script you will have to add, i.e., an if statement.

Comment: Hi Ruben! Thank you for commenting. Can i share the view link to my spreadsheet?

Comment: This is a view link for a copy of my original spreadsheet after I ran my script.    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dlS6rQqxz8t3YvHwMj8CxmVYPkCtJqrBpaZEAViQvx8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes you can, but still the question should be self contained. This means that somehow you should add the relevant details directly into the question body because the link might not work later.

Comment: Okay, I tried to update it. Please tell me if that is okay. I am new to scripts and to this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone "very very new to scripts", please spend some time learning the basics of JavaScript. As you are using Google Sheets as the container of your script you might start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

In this specific case, the easier solution to create slides for rows that have not been created yet, I think, is to add an if statement to check if the row hasn't an URL (equal to empty string), in such case create the slide, otherwise skip creating the slide. Since the script is overwriting the original data with `updatedContent`,  `updatedContents.push(row)` should be put out the if statement.

```js
// For every row, create a new slide by duplicating the master slide
// and replace the template variables with data from that row.
sheetContents.forEach(function(row) {

  if (row[6] === '') {

    // Insert a new slide by duplicating the master slide.
    let slide = masterSlide.duplicate();

    // Populate data in the slide that was created
    slide.replaceAllText("{{Date}}", row[1]);
    slide.replaceAllText("{{Topic}}", row[2]);
    slide.replaceAllText("{{EQ}}", row[3]);
    slide.replaceAllText("{{I can}}", row[4]);
    slide.replaceAllText("{{Objectives}}", row[5]);

    // Create the URL for the slide using the deck's ID and the ID
    // of the slide.
    let slideUrl = `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/${deck.getId()}/present#slide=id.${slide.getObjectId()}`;

    // Add this URL to the 4th column of the row and add this row
    // to the data to be written back to the sheet.
    row[6] = slideUrl;        
  }
  updatedContents.push(row);
});
```

Comment: So to do this, I will need to only have the rows I'm using in the spreadsheet. Right? It still ran all 80 rows that I have in the sheet. I would like to only run it if the url is blank and there is something in the date. Is that possible?

Comment: And now it's not bringing the url back. This is what it is saying: Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 7 but the range has 12.

Comment: @MeganPierce Regarding your last comment move `updatedContents.push(row);` out of the if statement (answer updated). Regarding the first comment, you have to decide how you want to handle the task in hands, i.e.  you might make your script to move the processed rows to a different sheet, so you keep one sheet to be used only for data entry and the other as a report / log.  You could add  as many conditions as you need, usually this is done by using booleans operators,  `&&`(AND) and `||` (OR).

Comment: Thank you for your help. You are right, I do need to study this more. I have been reading and wanted to jump in and try as that I how I learn best. I got stuck trying to do this and found this site where others were asking for help and thought it might help me learn more as well. Thank you for your patience with me.